# nestjs-i18n Translation handlebars templates not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, handlebars.js

**Handlebars template not translating by** [nestjs-i18n](https://nestjs-i18n.com/quick-start)

app.module.ts

```
@Global()
@Module({
imports: [
      I18nModule.forRoot({
      fallbackLanguage: 'en',
      loaderOptions: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/i18n/'),
        watch: true,
      },
      resolvers: [
        { use: HeaderResolver, options: ['lang'] },
        AcceptLanguageResolver,
      ],
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

mail.module.ts
[doc](https://nestjs-i18n.com/guides/mailer)

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [I18nService],
      useFactory: (i18n: I18nService) => ({
        transport: {
          host: process.env.MAILER_HOST,
          port: +process.env.MAILER_PORT,
          ignoreTLS: true,
          secure: true,
          auth: {
            user: process.env.MAILER_USER,
            pass: process.env.MAILER_PASS,
          },
        },
        defaults: {
          from: '"No Reply" <no-reply@localhost>',
        },
        preview: true,
        template: {
          dir: path.join(__dirname, '../resources/mail/templates/'),
          adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter({ t: i18n.hbsHelper }),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [MailService],
  exports: [MailService],
})
export class MailModule {}
```

src/i18n/fr/common.json
`"HELLO": "Bonjour",`

src/i18n/en/common.json
`"HELLO": "Hello",`

src/resources/mail/templates/test.hbs

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ t 'common.HELLO' }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

call api endpoint with curl
`curl -X POST http://localhost:8009/api/message -H "lang: fr"`

in email preview i see

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

instead of Bonjour

Translations in another places (f.e. validation) working ok

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3):

Same issue. As I can see in `src/services/i18n.service.ts`, property `i18nLang` is required in `option.data.root`. I think it means that we should provide property `i18nLang` in object, which we pass to template. In my case, I get lang value from `I18nContext` from controller.

F.E. I pass object in tis form

```
  context: {
    user,
    i18nLang,
  },
```

Comment: This worked, but why does nest doesn't resolve it using resolvers?. I've used QueryResolver, which grabs language in the request, eg. /customer?l=en and it doesnt automatically set the i18nLang based on the query, my solution is grabbing language in the query, and passing it by parameters to the sendEmail function, which seems like a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience I18nService doesnt have access to data from Resolvers. Have you tried with I18nContext or getI18nContextFromRequest? When I used them Resolvers were able to set the language.

I did another check and saw that Stas Pyatnicyn's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73139293/15741905) works definitely.

I think he mentions this line in the `hbsHelper` function

```
const lang = options.lookupProperty(options.data.root, 'i18nLang');
```

But I couldnt follow up what exactly `lookupProperty()` does. If he can explain it, it would be very much appreciated.

Its really weird that there is no documentation about this and thanks him a lot for finding out the solution.